# How can I stop external js script from stopping my fetch POST request?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, fetch, shopify

My app generates a [custom product page](https://benny-test-store.myshopify.com/products/summer-shoe-sales) on a Shopify store. I use Vue3 for the frontend. There are other apps running js on the page, e.g. live chat, push notification pop-up, GDPR cookie bar, etc. They are injected by the platform and I can't remove them. (Btw, these js are minified and hard to read)

My app has an add bundle to cart button on the floating footer to send a POST request to my server with Fetch API. But it's blocked by these irrelevant apps. I think these apps are monitoring if a POST / GET request is sent. They assume they are working on standard product pages but not custom one like mine.

I tried to implement a block list with [yett](https://github.com/elbywan/yett). But this passive way is not good enough. It's just a fix after the issue happens. Any way I can protect my fetch request without interfering by other js scripts?

```
let request = new Request('/create_new_product/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });

        let vm1 = this;
        fetch(request)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log('Success creating variant:', data);
          console.log('variant_id:', data.variant_id);
          // stopped here by other apps :-(
          if (data.variant_id) {
            vm1.addNewVariantToCart(this.variants, data.variant_id);
            vm1.$emit('clearall');
            setTimeout(function(){ vm1.isLoading = false; }, 2000);
          }
          else if (data.Error) {
            alert(data.Error);
            vm1.isLoading = false;
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          vm1.isLoading = false;
        });
```

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. *But it's blocked by these irrelevant apps. I think these apps are monitoring if a POST / GET request is sent. They assume they are working on standard product pages but not custom one like mine.* - the assumption is not enough, this needs to be confirmed. Please, narrow the question down by debugging it on your side, or provide a way to reproduce the problem, otherwise the answer would be "you probably can somehow".

Comment: I find that an app js checks the POST / GET request for an app js. For this issue, I can read the minified code. [Another js](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0078/9381/1251/t/13/assets/booster.js) is giving 415 when I send a POST request. I couldn't understand this one.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can get help at this point. You didn't provide a link that reproduces it. Others can't see what you see. Even if they do and this is caused by obfuscated files that you showed, it requires some dedicated work to reverse engineer it, only to find that it patches `fetch` and XHR to the point they cannot be recovered, and even if they can, this would possibly be against platform license. You can start by writing a script that replaces `String.fromCharCode(...)` with their evaluated results to understand what happens and inspecting `window.fetch.toString()` source code

Comment: OK, I've added the link to my demo page. And yes, the difficult part is that it's hard to reproduce. When I know an app is causing me an issue, I already put it on my block list so that the js couldn't run. 

But there are tens of thousands of apps. I don't know which one the users installs and which one causes me the issue. I just can't study one by one and money patch each app js. Now I just wait for user report and some users just delete my app and go away

Comment: From what I see, fetch is patched, and XHR is not, so you can try to use it directly or with Axios instead of fetch. But that XHR is not patched may change any moment. This is what you could do yourself by examining window.fetch.toString(), etc. You obviously can't prevent injected scripts from being evaluated because they are evaluated prior to yours, and this would likely be against platform rules.